# Home userdir is not working after enabled on Apache2

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2, mod-userdir

I'm trying to enable userdir in Apache2 but I only receive a blank page.

I used:

```
a2enmod userdir 
service apache2 restart
```

My conf file /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public_html
    UserDir disabled root

    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
        Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
        Require method GET POST OPTIONS
         
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

I only can list files and directories, php pages is blank.

I check in /var/www/html and works, but not in user home dir.

How can configure to enable userdir?

Comment: What does your logs say?

Comment: See here access.log and error.log
https://pastebin.com/cRSdpY0R

Comment: In the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.3.conf, I have : # Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default
# 
# To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_flag engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule> A flag engine On should be required.